# password_hash in `insert` does not match type :string

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my user context I define a password_hash field of type string:

```
defmodule Catsdogs.UserContext.User do
use Ecto.Schema
import Ecto.Changeset

@acceptable_roles ["Admin", "Manager", "User"]

schema "users" do
  field :username, :string
  field :password, :string, virtual: true
  field :password_hash, :string
  field :role, :string, default: "User"
end

def get_acceptable_roles, do: @acceptable_roles

@doc false
def changeset(user, attrs) do
  user
   |> cast(attrs, [:username, :password, :role])
   |> validate_required([:username, :password, :role])
   |> validate_inclusion(:role, @acceptable_roles)
   |> put_password_hash()
end

defp put_password_hash(%Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} = changeset) do
  change(changeset, password_hash: Pbkdf2.add_hash(password))
end

defp put_password_hash(changeset), do: changeset

end
```

In my seeds.exs, I create a dummy user

```
{:ok, _cs} =
Catsdogs.UserContext.create_user(%{
  "password" => "t",
  "role" => "Manager",
  "username" => "manager"
})
```

Why is it denying my password hash field when adding a user, saying that it does not match type :string, when surely it does?

```
(Ecto.ChangeError) value `%{password_hash: "$pbkdf2-sha512$160000$XfB4A.b62vcGfH2PpmDw8A$E9MNNWHftlgSJnYSwoc1cbUrsDQy24c.MbRdOLdeDBzwnWEOuFzVZuZW8noci3.H/WWUOuF34AQy9ndYIA/gIA"}` for `Catsdogs.UserContext.User.password_hash` in `insert` does not match type :string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear though: `%{password_hash: "$pbkdf2-sha512$160000$XfB4A.b62vcGfH2PpmDw8A$E9MNNWHftlgSJnYSwoc1cbUrsDQy24c.MbRdOLdeDBzwnWEOuFzVZuZW8noci3.H/WWUOuF34AQy9ndYIA/gIA"}` does not match a string. That's because it's a map.

It looks like you made a small error when using the code from [here](https://hexdocs.pm/pbkdf2_elixir/Pbkdf2.html#add_hash/2-example-with-ecto):

```
defp put_pass_hash(%Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes:
    %{password: password}} = changeset) do
  change(changeset, Pbkdf2.add_hash(password)) # <-- CHANGE THIS LINE
end

defp put_pass_hash(changeset), do: changeset
```

Comment: Yes I had tried that, but it didn't work, but that is indeed what had to be changed it works now since I made a naming mistake in my migrations file.